# Getting records from 2 tables with common an uncommon columns

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Below is similar example of the issue I have:

if I have this *table 1*:

| Patient ID | Name | Check in Date | order name | preformed by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack | 12/sep/2002 | xray | Dr.Amal |
| 2 | Nora | 15/oct/2002 | ultrasound | Dr.Goerge |
| 1 | Jack | 13/nov/2003 | Medicine | Dr.Fred |

*table 2*:

| Patient ID | Name | Check in Date | order name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack | 14/Jun/2002 | xray 2 |
| 2 | Nora | 15/oct/2002 | ultrasound |
| 1 | Jack | 13/nov/2003 | Medicine |
| 3 | Rafael | 13/nov/2003 | Vaccine |

The result I need is as the following:

| Name | Check in Date | order name | preformed by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 12/sep/2002 | xray | Dr.Amal |
| Nora | 15/oct/2002 | ultrasound | Dr.Goerge |
| Jack | 13/nov/2003 | Medicine | Dr.Fred |
| Jack | 14/Jun/2002 | xray 2 | Null |
| Rafael | 13/nov/2003 | Vaccine | Null |

If you noticed the result I need is all records of table 1 and all records of table 2 with no duplication and joining the same common fields and adding 'Preformed by' column from Table 1. I tried using 'UNION' as the following:

```
SELECT Name, Check_in_Date, order_name,preformed_by
  FROM table1 
UNION 
SELECT Name, Check_in_Date, order_name,''
  FROM table2
```

the result I get is 2 records for each patient with the same date one with preformed by one with null as the following:

| Name | Check in Date | order name | preformed by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 12/sep/2002 | xray | Dr.Amal |
| Nora | 15/oct/2002 | ultrasound | Dr.Goerge |
| Nora | 15/oct/2002 | ultrasound | Null |
| Jack | 13/nov/2003 | Medicine | Dr.Fred |
| Jack | 13/nov/2003 | Medicine | null |
| Jack | 14/Jun/2002 | xray 2 | Null |
| Rafael | 13/nov/2003 | Vaccine | Null |

If the same ID has same check in date in both table it must return the preformed by of table 1 not null How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is a **`FULL JOIN`** matching by those three columns along with **`NVL()`** function in order to bring  the values
from *table2* which return `null` from *table1* such as

```
SELECT NVL(t1.name,t2.name) AS name,
       NVL(t1.check_in_date,t2.check_in_date) AS check_in_date,
       NVL(t1.order_name,t2.order_name) AS order_name,
       t1.preformed_by 
  FROM table1 t1
  FULL JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.name = t2.name
   AND t1.check_in_date = t2.check_in_date
   AND t1.order_name = t2.order_name
```

***or*** another method uses **`UNION`** to filter out duplicates and then applies an `OUTER JOIN` such as

```
SELECT tt.name, tt.check_in_date, tt.order_name, t1.preformed_by 
  FROM (
        SELECT name, check_in_date, order_name FROM table1 UNION
        SELECT name, check_in_date, order_name FROM table2
       ) tt
  LEFT JOIN table1 t1
    ON t1.name = tt.name
   AND t1.check_in_date = tt.check_in_date
   AND t1.order_name = tt.order_name
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/2Gh-aLLg)</kbd>

Comment: You may also use `USING(<column list>)` instead of `ON` to remove the need of `NVL` (Oracle will place it implicitly) and `NATURAL FULL JOIN` to remove the need to specify columns (but join on all matching names is a design flaw). I've added such a query based on the fiddle of this answer: https://dbfiddle.uk/aQA15P8T

Comment: Thank you very much your are awesome! it worked perfectly using NVL.

Comment: you're welcome @proR , have a good study!